# Human-readable format for storing key–value pairs

Tags: data, serialization

I am looking for a format to write key–value pairs, where keys and
values are delimited by colons.  The values either:

1. follow immediately after the colon (whitespace between the colon and
   the first non-whitespace character is stripped) and is terminated by
   a newline; or
2. Starts on the next line indented from the baseline of where the key
   is, and is terminated by deindentation.  Leading and trailing
   whitespaces are stripped.

Examples (1):

```
Nullam: eu ante vel est convallis dignissim.
Fusce suscipit: wisi nec facilisis facilisis, …
```

Examples (2):

```
Nunc:
    porta vulputate tellus.  Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.  Sed bibendum.
    Aliquam posuere.  Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus
    tellus malesuada massa, quis varius mi purus non odio.  Pellentesque
    condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum augue ornare nulla,
    non luctus diam neque sit amet urna.
Curabitur:
    vulputate vestibulum lorem.  Fusce sagittis, libero non molestie
    mollis, magna orci ultrices dolor, at vulputate neque nulla lacinia
    eros.  Sed id ligula quis est convallis tempor.  Curabitur lacinia
    pulvinar nibh.  Nam a sapien.
```

As an alternative to the above, if a multi-line value is allowed to
begin on the same line as the key, then the first line is treated as a
“leading indent” (I don’t know the word for this).  So with this format,
this:

```
Nunc: porta vulputate tellus.  Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.  Sed bibendum.
    Aliquam posuere.  Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus
    tellus malesuada massa, quis varius mi purus non odio.  Pellentesque
    condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum augue ornare nulla,
    non luctus diam neque sit amet urna.
```

Would be equivalent to this (using point № 2):

```
Nunc:
    porta vulputate tellus.  Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.  Sed bibendum.
    Aliquam posuere.  Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus
    tellus malesuada massa, quis varius mi purus non odio.  Pellentesque
    condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum augue ornare nulla,
    non luctus diam neque sit amet urna.
```

## Parsing indented blocks

In case it matters and the text cannot just be passed through, a single
newline should be treated as equivalent to a space.  Two consecutive
newlines marks the beginning of a new paragraph or something like that,
so those should not be treated as two spaces.

## Intended use

I intend to use this format to store metadata relating to Git, which is
why I want the format to look like the “trailer” part of a Git commit
message:

Which are in turn inspired by RFC 822 e-mail headers.

Unlike most key–value pairs I’ve seen in Git commit messages, I want to
be able to store longer strings (such as free-form prose) and nested
key–value pairs.

## YAML

I am aware that [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) has
whitespace-sensitive delimiters, and also a way to express multi-line,
wrapped values:

```
data: >
   Wrapped text
   will be folded
   into a single
   paragraph

   Blank lines denote
   paragraph breaks
```

This is the closest to what I want that I’ve come across.

Comment: Not sure if this really fits SR – as we recommend software, not formats, algorithms etc. That apart, Yaml was the first thing coming to my mind as well – as `{"json": "wouldn't really reflect your needs"}` (though being also close to it). Seeing your second example makes me think of *Markdown Extra* (definition lists). // Again that raises the question: What OS must be supported, what tools etc. The latter would be putting the cart before the horse on this site :)

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the feedback. I was unsure about whether formats was under the domain of this site. Maybe Unix/Linux or Superuser would be better.

Comment: Not sure which place would fit best. But if you found your format, you're welcome to ask here for programs that can deal with it (and meet the criteria important to you :)

Comment: Your question is essentially defining a format, not asking for one.  You have specified your format.  If you're asking whether there is software that will parse that exact format, the answer is probably not, since you just made it up.

Comment: @BrenBarn You’re right.  I asked for a format in case anyone knows about a format that has this behavior, or most probably provides this as a subset of the whole format.  That way I am a little more assured, in the case that I get no replies, that I wouldn’t be reinventing some format if I choose to implement it myself. :-)